# Probability distribution of a sequence of i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, random-walk

I have a sequence of random variables, $$X_0, X_1, \ldots, X_n, \ldots$$ defined in a probability space where $$X_0 = 0$$ by definition, and $$X_n = r_1(x) + r_2(x) + \cdots + r_n(x), \quad n \ge 1,$$ where $r(x)$ is the rademacher function, with $x$ any real number in the interval $[0,1)$. The sequence of random variables given describes a random walk in the set of integers.

I want to find the distribution of the $X$ in the space given by $A = \{-n, -n + 2, \ldots , n - 2, n\}$ is

$$P(X_n=k) = \frac 1 {2^n}\cdot \binom n {(n - k)/2} \text{ when } k \in A.$$

and that the probability is zero when $$ k \in \mathbb{Z}\smallsetminus A$$

I know how to calculate the distribution of a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, like they are in this problem, but the restriction to the set $A$ is troubling me out. Any help?

Comment: What is the thing you've denoted by lower-case $x \text{?} \qquad$

Comment: any real number in the interval [0,1); I will edit. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you edited my post; there is a binomial coefficient that you took off. that n/[(n-k)/2] is a binomial coefficient. I will appreciate if you edit back

Comment: @Dinitri : What you had did not look like a binomial coefficient, but now I've formatted it like a binomial coefficient.

Comment: This is just a convoluted way of describing a random walk with an equal chance of going up or down by $1$. Is your question how to establish that it is a random walk so described or how to show the distribution of such a random walk is what you wrote down? It should be clear that the distribution of this only has support on $A.$

Comment: It is clear that the distribution only has suport on A only, because if k is an integer but not in A I cannot have my random variable to be k if k is not on the set. My problem is how to show, formaly, why the distribution is what I wrote down. I cannot see why, for example, the (n - k)/2 should appear.

Comment: @Dimitri You gotta @ people if you want them informed you replied to them. If at each step instead of equal chance of moving $\pm 1$ you had equal chance of moving $0$ or $1,$ then your position after $n$ steps would be binomial distributed. That's where the binomial coefficient comes from. Then it just takes a little bit to map this to the situation where it's $\pm 1.$ For instance say there's $10$ steps. Say in the $0$-$1$ case you end up at $4$ which means four $1$'s and six $0$'s. That maps to four $1$'s and six $-1$'s which means you wind up at $-2.$ There's a simple relationship here.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreenyou are right; maybe I wasn't clear, but I am trying to do without the combinatorial argument but by direct integration in the probability space with lebesgue integral. My atempt was to write P(X_n = k) = |{x\in [0,1) : X_n = k}| = integral of X_n over the set A. That is where I got stucked. I know that the probability of the rademacher function being 1 or -1 is 1/2, thus n rademacher function being independent give me the 1/2^n factor. I don't know how to construct the binomial coeficient with the integral.